# Best way to implement a Timer Rest API in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, api, timer

I have to implement an application to count the time of tasks. For example, an User could start and stop a determinate task and I have to know the time he spent  on it. I could store and calculate the begin and end time, but I would like to know if there is a possiblity to implement a REST API in C# that had three methods in order to my application could "call it" with web services.

- StartTimer(): when an user pressed the start button in some application, this API method will be "called" and the timer starts counting. After 4 hours and if a user not closed the task (the "StopTime()" method wasn't "called") I want to do "something".
- CurrentTime(): return the atual spent time
- StopTime(): when an user pressed the stop button, this API method will be "called" and the timer stops, returning the timer value

I did some research and I found some information about System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer. I would like to know if using one of it (what is the best for this situation?) could be a good approach or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: This task is not a good one for REST, REST is stateless, it means has no knowledge about previous requests, of course you can create a service, static class or anything you want, but it's not the ideal transport for such a task. Also, think about scalability, if your REST API some day needs to be balanced in a cluster, it would not work unless you create a complex infrastructure (suppose Start is called in server A and Stop is called on server B). For tasks like this better use something like WebSockets as it will maintain a connection while the consumer is using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put you timers on web server you can do following:

StartTimer method - create timer entity in database with [StartTime] field
CurrentTime method - find timer entity by id, calculate spent time like (CurrentTime - StartTime)
StopTimer - find timer by id, mark it as stopped, retun timer value

Additionaly you need background worker that run on schedule (i.e. every 5 min) and check timers that are timed out (4 hour in your case). Those worker should "do something" like send email to user.

If you need to stop timer **exactly** after 4 hours then modify background worker:

1) find timer that spent 3h 55min or more

2) use System.Threading.Timer to finish it